# Why does Google Chrome not recognize my SameSite cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies

I'm trying to explore how Google Chrome handles SameSite cookies. So by using the console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), I added an aditional key-value pair for the cookie of a certain website I have an account on. I inputted the following code:

```
document.cookie="SameSite=strict"
```

I checked the remaining cookie and all original key-value pairs are still there, along with the newly added "SameSite=strict" pair.

Now, the problem is that Chrome doesn't act like it is supposed to according to the specification of the SameSite cookie. For example: when I go to wikipedia.org and click on a link that directs me to the website of the cookie, I'm logged in. Normally I would not be logged in, because Chrome isn't supposed to send along the cookie due to the "SameSite=strict" pair.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why should you not be logged in in this scenario - because you're following an external link? Why?

Comment: When the SameSite value is set to "strict", the cookie is witheld with any cross-site usage. This means that even when following a link to another website (using <a href="...">), the cookie won't be sent along. This is also stated in [this blog](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SameSite is not a cookie value. It's a cookie flag, like httpOnly and secure. So you cannot set it like `document.cookie="SameSite=strict"`, because that sets a value.

Try with

```
document.cookie="mycookie=myvalue;SameSite=strict"
```

You can then observe in Chrome DevTools on the Application tab under Cookies that your cookie is in fact set as SameSite=strict, as opposed to just a plain cookie.